# Angular2 use [ngClass] with jpg dominate color

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jpeg

Sorry, the title may be a bit confusing.

I am looking for a solution to this use case:

I am returning an image and displaying it on a div. In the top right corner there is an overlay displaying an "x" allowing the user to dismiss the div. What I am looking for is a way that I can look at the image returned and if it is a black image the "x" would be white and if it is a white image the "x" would be black.

I would like to avoid any third party solutions if at all possible.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: by "black" and "white", do you mean *completely*? If not, you would have to find a way to differentiate a "white" image from a "black" one.

Comment: Yeah i think it would have to be "an image with more dark colors" vs "an image with more light colors", and then set some sort of limit to when it actually changes.

Comment: you'd need to find a third party library, otherwise you're gonna have to write a long algorithm

Comment: Is there a name for doing that process? I have been looking, but I am unsure what to even call it